# Thermal fuse circuit question

Tags: fuses, thermal

DIY oven repair question.

My oven has two thermal fuses, one is definately blown, I'm not sure about the other.

Are these typically normally closed cicuit (open when hot) or could they be the other way round?

I have two new ones, one is rated at 190C and is closed circuit when measured across the terminals, the other is rated 150C and measures open circuit  - I'm wondering if they've sent me a faulty one.

Comment: How do you know "one is definitely blown"?  If it is definitely blown, then whatever state it is in (open/closed) is the wrong state for normal operation.

Comment: One is badly burnt and is basically the cause for the oven to not work. The other one, which is in a different position "looks" fine, but is also open circuit. My assumption is that they should both be closed - but, I could be wrong....

Answer (score 1):

[Thermal fuses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_cutoff) (also known as "thermal cutoffs,") are normally conducting.  They stop conducting (permanently) when they are exposed to a temperature that exceeds their rating.

If you have a new thermal fuse that reads open, then it is bad.  A thermal fuse should read as a short circuit when it is good and as an open circuit when it is blown.

Thermal switches are also normally conducting.  They should read as a short circuit when cool and open when hot.

---

Make sure to replace the fuses with the correct current and temperature ratings.

- If the current rating is too low, the fuse will burn out from over heating.
- If the temperature rating is too low then the fuse will blow in normal use.
- If the temperature rating is too high then fuse won't blow when it should, allowing your device to overheat and potentially damage itself or your house.

Comment: Note that thermal fuses and switches are generally the "normally-closed" variety, but there are some "normally-open" variants.  Whether N.O. would be used in an oven is unlikely, but not impossible; all depends on how it was engineered.  It may be possible to tell from the schematic (if available) which type it is.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are saying it's a fuse, then it should definitely be "normally closed."

You see, based on the definition "fuse" [from wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuse_(electrical)) "a metal wire or strip that melts when too much current flows through it, thereby stopping or interrupting the current.", which means it is a low resistance component allowing high current to pass through only for a small duration.

The operation of a fuse is different based on the application. For athermal fuse, the heat is the measurement element. Based on how the thermal fuse works [you can find it here](http://www.thermalcutoff.com/en/document/gfile.php?fn=thermal-fuse-operation-principle), when the temperature rises above the specified limits, a component in the fuse melts and disconnect the whole circuit.

Use digital multimeter on resistance mode to see if it is a NO or NC conducting.  Use diode mode or beep mode. If it measures only 100 ohms, if the measurement is less then it will beep if not it will display an ohms value.